# Renaming multiple files at once

Tags: terminal, rename, filenames, file-rename

I have a large data set of files that are all named like this:

```
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10157.ratio_9
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10158.ratio_0
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10159.ratio_130
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10160.ratio_7
```

But of course in hindsight this is going to make reading in the files difficult since I'll need the file names and each may have a different ratio. Is there a way to rename all the files at once so that the ratio_* is gone?

Ideally I'd like them to be in this form:

```
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10157
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10158
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10159
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10160
```

Comment: What does [tag:terminal] have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
//set X to all files of the form proportional.rank
X=$(ls proportional.rank*) 

//print out to check X is set
echo $X 

//loop over all files of X
for i in $X ; do
  before_stem=${i%.ratio_*} //what I want to keep
  after_stem=${i#*.ratio_}  //what I don't want
  new_end =$(printf ".out" $after_stem) //give new ending
  mv $i ${before_stem}${new_end} //concatenate the new ending and old beginning
done
```

%: take everything before the pattern that follows the %

pound sign: take everything after the pattern that follows the #

printf: just like C printf

```
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10157.ratio_9
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10158.ratio_0
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10159.ratio_130
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10160.ratio_7
```

becomes

```
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10157.out
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10158.out
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10159.out
proportional.rank_9.cycle_10160.out
```